# SSH key issue on vagrant machine and Github on Mac

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, vagrant

I am currently having a problem to open the ~/.ssh/config file on the terminal.  I am currently using the vagrant machine. I read the information all over the sites and still could not come to the conclude to solve this problem that I am dealing with ssh.  I am providing the link;

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

You can see the information that I copied and pasted it on here; below.  For your information that I am still learning how to coding and how to troubleshooting the problems.  Unfortunately, I am unable to solve this problem relates to adding the SSH key.  I believe that I have to do this because I moved away and using different internet server now.  It might be the reason why I need to add new ssh key, which I already did in the previous steps.  I am currently on step #2 (example below) is when I am unable to open the ~/.ssh/config file to load the keys into ssh-agent and store the passphrases in the keychain on my computer.

If you're using macOS Sierra 10.12.2 or later, you will need to modify your ~/.ssh/config file to automatically load keys into the ssh-agent and store passphrases in your keychain.

First, check to see if your ~/.ssh/config file exists in the default location.

$ open ~/.ssh/config

> The file /Users/you/.ssh/config does not exist.
> If the file doesn't exist, create the file.

$ touch ~/.ssh/config
Open your ~/.ssh/config file, then modify the file, replacing ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 if you are not using the default location and name for your id_ed25519 key.

Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
Note: If you chose not to add a passphrase to your key, you should omit the UseKeychain line.

Here is the screenshot, so you can see where I am stuck at.

[image]

I hope this help you to explain me better on how to fix the ssh keys so I can go ahead and finish coding my projects and push the codes to Github.

Thank you for your time and patience in helping me to become a better software engineering.